# How does one force an element to move up with the margin tag in CSS? Ignoring the margin

Tags: html, css

In an example of code, it will actually go up maybe 50% but after I try to do more, it will stay the same due to a parent css tag.
How do I ignore this?

It's a huge pain in the ass!

I'm trying to do a backdrop in CSS, and then when I try to make the margin force the element up after 50%, it stays at the same margin height.

Any ideas?

EDIT HERE IS SOME CODE!

```
.backdropc {
background:#E7E7E7;
height:500px;
width:4500px;
margin-left:-100%;
margin-top:50px;

  border: solid #C3C3C3 1px;}
```

css

html:

```
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/153025425" width="550" height="305" style="margin-top:-495% !important;"frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Thank you.

Comment: any code we can play around with?

Comment: Yes. Just added some! Thank you.

Comment: have you tried using `position`?

Comment: Holy shit Sam. Thank you -- honestly, I have no clue why I didn't try that tag before...

Comment: glad to help you.. happy coding.. =)

Comment: your iframe have this inline css `style="margin-top:-495% !important;"` overriding any margin-top css that you place on the internal/external css. **delete this immediately**

Answer (score 0):

Margin has its limitations. In this case, the best solution may be using relative, fixed, or absolute positioning. While I wouldn’t recommend using relative positioning often, as long as it doesn’t interfere with the rest of your site, it is the easiest to implement because the rest of your page doesn’t move around. Here’s how to do it with external or internal styling.

```
iframe {
    position: relative;
    top: -50%;
}
```

You can also do it with inline styling.

```
<iframe style=“position: relative; top: -50%” >
```

Hope this helps!